# Setting up cookies for a newsletter popup

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am trying to set up cookies that expire in 7 days after clicking the 'x' on the modal. I can't figure out why it doesn't want to save the cookie. Below is the code I am using. The site is [goodbooks.io](https://www.goodbooks.io).

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"> </script>

<script>
    var cookieName = 'popupClosed';

    if(typeof Cookies.get(cookieName) !== 'undefined') {
        $('.popup-wrapper, .preview-page, .popup-content-wrapper, .popup').remove();
    }

    $('.close-popup').on('click'), function(){
        Cookies.set(cookieName, 'value', { expires: 7});

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`$('.close-popup').on('click'), function(){` ... `}`

to

`$('.close-popup').on('click', function(){` ... `})`

Comment: Thank you! Missed that bracket

Answer (score 2):

in PHP

```
<?php
header('Test 123 I Love Bacon'); // just to test header_ list

setcookie('cookieName','cookieValue123',time()+604800, "example.com");
if(isset($_COOKIE['cookieName']) && $_COOKIE['cookieName'] == 'cookieValue123')
 {
     var_dump(headers_list()); // show headers to be sent to the browser
}
?>
```